# Flask websocket send message to specific client

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

Im using Flask websocket . and  websocket  server is running in port 5000

These are the three different clients listening the websocket server
Based on the client Id , I want to send different messages to different client.

In my above , all weebsockets clients receive all the messages.
Please let me Is there any way to Based on the client Id , I want to send different messages to different client.

```
ws://127.0.0.1:5000/getMessage?clientId=C10
ws://127.0.0.1:5000/getMessage?clientId=C20
ws://127.0.0.1:5000/getMessage?clientId=C30

from geventwebsocket.exceptions import WebSocketError
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
import gevent
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets
from gevent import pywsgi, Greenlet
from gevent.event import Event

if request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket'):
    ws = request.environ['wsgi.websocket']
    reqBody = request.args
    event = Event()
    ws_event.append((ws, event, None))

for ws, event, _ in ws_event:
    try:
        ws.send("Hello Message")
    except WebSocketError as e:
        event.set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add the client's ID to your messages and make each client process only messages that contain its ID.

For example, you can prepend each message with a client ID like so `"<clientId>:Hello Message"`. A message for `C10` becomes `"C10:Hello Message"`. Every client will receive this message but only `C10` will act on it.